# IE11 возвращает ошибку "Объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод"

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

Во всех браузерах Mozila, Yandex, Chrome, Vivaldi. Все работает стабильно, но вот в IE, вылетает ошибка:

> "Объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод"

на строке:

```
req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
```

не могу понять почему, ниже привожу кусок кода:

```
function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlhttp
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e1) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function ask_values() {
    req = getXmlHttp();
    req.open('POST', 'GetChart.cgi?', true);
    req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    //req.responseType = 'blob';
    req.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
    req.send(time*16);
}
```

Заранее Спасибо.

Comment: добавьте функцию `getXmlHttp()`

Comment: а что возвращает `getXmlHttp();`?

Comment: @Grundy с разницей в 2 секунды :D

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, я еще и подредактировать успел

Comment: добавил функцию

Comment: это все из-за этой функции. Основными браузерами давно поддерживается `XMLHttpRequest` зачем возвращаться и использовать ActiveX?

Comment: Проблема этой функции в том, что для семейства IE выбор осуществляется в сторону `ActiveX` даже если `XMLHttpRequest` уже реализован, и, как видно из вопроса, некоторые возможности у этих объектов отличаются.